# Can blue/green deployment be used for acceptance testing

Tags: testing, acceptance, blue-green-deployment

Could an environment properly setup for blue/green deployment be leveraged for acceptance tests?

What advantages/risks would you see there?

Basically I would imagine a green environment would be used to run a few acceptance tests. If passed, switch the traffic to green and proceed with the regular blue/green scenario.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it can, but as with everything - it depends.

Blue / Green deployment definitions are never quite prescriptive when it comes to what to do with the data - and that will be your main concern when running acceptance tests on the non-live environment.

If your acceptance tests do not affect data at all, then yes, this would be the ideal time to run them.  If, however, there is data changed by the tests then when you switch over, the data changes are now in production - if this is acceptable, then so is your proposal.